# Can you apply drop-shadow on ::after?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Is it possible to apply the drop-shadow filter to ::after?

I tried this, `box-shadow` works on `::after`, but not `filter:drop-shadow`:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
span.shadow-box::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.shadow-filter::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px green);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="shadow-box">Box-shadow</span>
<span class="shadow-filter">Drop-shadow</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px green);

its work on images like background ...etc

could see like below, just add background-color in after

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
span.shadow-box::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.shadow-filter::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px green);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="shadow-box">Box-shadow</span>
<span class="shadow-filter">Drop-shadow</span>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was an unexpected answer!